# Which American twin tilt-rotor aircraft is this a scale-model of?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What aircraft is this model?

[image: side view of scale-model twin tilt-rotor aircraft]

[image: three-quarters view of scale-model twin tilt-rotor aircraft]

[image: front view of scale-model twin tilt-rotor aircraft]

(photos: own work)

Comment: The registration decal 227316 seems to have been pinched from a P-47 model with a rather excellent native American paint scheme
 https://www.scalemates.com/kits/academy-2174-p-47d-thunderbolt-bubble-top--107421

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like [the Bell XV-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_XV-3), "an American tiltrotor aircraft developed by Bell Helicopter for a joint research program between the United States Air Force and the United States Army in order to explore convertiplane technologies."

[image: Bell XV-3]

Answer (score 1):

Bell XV-3. The Transcendental Aircraft 1-G was slightly diferent. Kind of H-34 Choctaw looking compared to the XV-3.

Comment: Welcome to Av.se. Can you elaborate any on your answer, maybe explaining where the two designs differed & what features in the OP's photo are more similar to the XV-3? As it stands, a reader has little basis to see the validity of your answer, beyond having "read it on the internet".